# Migrating TFS 2012 to VSO - Template Issues

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

I am attempting to migrate from an on-premise installation of TFS 2012 to Visual Studio Online.  I have a handful of projects that have been in existence since TFS 2005 and have been upgraded/migrated up to 2012.  Only one of those projects has any significant work item activity that I really need to maintain.

That project is using the MSF for Agile Software Development 6.2 template.  I have never made any customizations to the template to my knowledge over the years.  However, since it has been upgraded / migrated I am not surprised that the template is causing the OpsHub utility issues.

For every Work Item Type in the project, the fields 'Area Id' and 'Iteration Id' show as red errors on the validation screen of the tool for this specific project.

I have already tried the solutions suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27926927/migrating-tfs-2010-to-visual-studio-online), but it seems to have made no difference whatsoever.  The template on VSO is MSF for Agile Development 2013.3.  After looking at the WIT definition files in that template I can see that there is no 'Area Id' or 'Iteration Id' fields (or 'AreaID' or 'IterationId' for that matter) defined.  However, in the 6.2 templates that field is specifically defined.

I am sure this has something to do with those being System defined fields and no longer needing to be defined in the individual work item templates or something of that nature.  The fields cannot be deleted because they are System fields.

In any case, I have not been able to find a solution to this problem so that I can complete running the OpsHub tool to migrate this main project over.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

As an aside, every one of my projects are showing 'Template Customization or Template Mismatch' errors.  For the meantime, I am just trying to resolve the issues with this one main project.  I may be able to forego migrating the Work Item Data for some of the other projects.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Can you check in templates if FIELD name="Area ID" or FIELD name="Area Id" same for Iteration Id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the move from 2008 to 2010 Microsoft changed a number of the built in fields. These fields do not appear in the template, but if you export the work item type from the instance of the process template you will see them.

Effectively an upgraded server has built in fields that never changed and the OpsHub tool craps out on fields that it should be ignoring.

The only solution, bar OpsHub fixing it, would be to try and change the field names to match what is expected.

You can use the witadmin.exe to make the change.