# OpsHub Process Templates Do Not Match

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

We are migrating a tfs in-house instance to VSO. This server began as tfs08 then upgraded to tfs10. I am running into an error Process Templates Do Not Match, which makes sense but we are not using custom templates. The process template is MSF for Agile Software Development v5.0. Does this process template need to be modified before it will map to VSO? here is the list of incompatibilities I receive on all projects.

[image]

Update after Name changes. Anyone know what these 2 remaining fields translate to? I tried renaming in case they had leading or trailing spaces but no luck.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer following thread. Hope answer provided in the thread will help you resolving the issue.

[Migrating TFS 2010 to Visual Studio Online](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27926927/migrating-tfs-2010-to-visual-studio-online/28810772#28810772)

Thanks & Regards
OpsHub Support

Comment: Thanks I saw that one earlier and was going to go down that path but I was wondering if there was a source that showed what the new naming conventions were for the VSO online template because Rank does not require a space

Comment: Disregard, it looks like these 2 fields were deprecated. I ended up importing the [Bug], [User Story] and [Shared Steps] templates from MSF for Agile Software Development v5 for all projects since we didn't do any customization.