# TFS 2012 On-Premise Migration to Visual Studio Online

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

I am looking to migrate from TFS 2012 on-premises to Visual Studio Online using the OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility. I have run into an issue that I can't seem to find a resolution for. To eliminate any customization, I have created a brand new team project in TFS 2012 using the process template SCRUM 2.0. I did nothing else after creating that new project. The goal was to run the migration utility on this new project to see if I can get it to work. During the migration, it fails with the error "Template Customization or Template Mismatch Error". Since I know for sure we never modified the SCRUM 2.0 process template that I used to create this new project, I assume the error is more with the fact that TFS 2012 SCRUM 2.0 template is different that Visual Studio Online. Using TFS Team Project manager utility I can see they are quite different.

So the question is, does OpsHub not support migration from TFS 2012 to Visual Studio Online when no customization to process template was made? It does not look like it does unless I am missing something. Can anyone help me determine what I need to do to make this migration a success.

Thanks,

Comment: Below is the results of the "View Customization Details" after error appears   
  
Product Backlog Item  
    |__ RelatedLinkCount  
    |__ AreaID  
    |__ AttachedFileCount  
    |__ HyperLinkCount  
    |__ ExternalLinkCount  
    |__ IterationID  
  
The above is repeated for each of the following  
- Feedback Request  
- Task  
- Impediment  
- Code Review Request  
- Code Review Response  
- Shared Steps  
- Feedback Response  
- Bug  
- Test Case

Answer (score 0):

The OpsHub tool supports migration only when the local template matches the target template. You will need to upgrade your Scrum team project to the latest scrum template to proceed.

You can also use the TFS Integration Tools to migrate with a mapping between the two templates. That might work better for you, but the TFSIP is significantly more complicated than the free OpsHub took. But that complexity brings features.

Answer (score 0):

Tool is throwing error because the fields listed in error have display name do not match fields in VSO. In upgraded process template version 2.2 and other above version they have space included in display name such as *Related Link Count*. To overcome this error you can upgrade the process template version to 2.2 or use witadmin.exe tool to change the field display name. For more details visit [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27926927/migrating-tfs-2010-to-visual-studio-online/28810772#28810772)